# Java Development kit error

Tags: java

I am trying to install java development kit on windows 7 32 bit.I downloaded the file x86 from oracle website.During the installation when it goes to update registration component i have an error named"ERROR 1359.An Internal Error occured".SO please help me to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem: "Error 1359.An internal error occured." while installing Java 7.

The Solution:  Uninstall Windows Update KB2918614 - Security update for Windows Installer Service: August 12, 2014

In Windows 7:

1. Open your Start Menu > Control Panel > Programs and Features (sometimes called "Add or remove programs").
2. Click View Installed Updates and locate `KB2918614`. You can use <kbd>F3</kbd> to find it easier.
3. Right-click on the the update and Uninstall.  Reboot when completed.

This will allow you to successfully install Java 7 for Windows 7 (32/64).

References:
[1] http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2318344/installing-java-error-1359-internal-error-occurred.html
[2] https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2289

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with your system files, try disabling your system restore and see if it works.

I had the same issue a fairly long time ago, to fix it I simply upgraded from an old OS service pack to a newer one, that alone basically refreshes most if not all system files which is almost equivalent to a re-install.

If *all* doesn't work then I would suggest backing up and re-installing your OS. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as a different user before you doing anything else.

1. Hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> and right-click on your installer, then choose "Run as a different user".
2. Enter the administrator credentials; if it is disabled you will need to enable it manually or use the `net use` command.
3. After entering the credentials, proceed with the installation and see how it goes.